# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException in Import Resource with @ImportResource in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I have two packages A and B.
Package A has a config class named inject/spring/ClientConfiguration.java which has structure like

```
@Configuration
public class ClientConfiguration {

@Bean
public ABCWrapper aBCWrapper() {
    return new ABCWrapperImpl();
}

@Bean
public X.ClientConfiguration clientConfig() {
    return new ClientConfiguration()
}}
```

A.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans classpath:org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/util classpath:org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-4.2.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context classpath:org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-4.2.xsd
 ">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.inject.spring"/>
```

now in package B i want to use the bean aBCWrapper.
So the config is

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({ "classpath*:A.xml" })
public class BConfig {

@Autowired
private com.inject.spring.ClientConfiguration abcClientConfiguration;

@Bean
public ABCPublisher aBCPublisher() {
    return new ABCPublisher(abcClientConfiguration.aBCWrapper());
}
}
```

But i am getting the exception 
exception is

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.inject.spring.ClientConfiguration' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Seems like i am making a silly mistake 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are exposing the bean twice. You don't need an additional bean importing the `A.xml` is enough. That will load the `ClientConfiguration` which exposes the bean.

Comment: public ABCPublisher aBCPublisher() {
        return new ABCPublisher(abcClientConfiguration.aBCWrapper());
    }

Comment: tried using this as well but the same exception ,

Comment: Again you don't need the configuration, just auto wire the `ABCWrapper` NOT the configuration class.

Comment: and how that can be done ?

Comment: Just auto wire it.

Comment: still not working

Comment: Then your configuration is wrong and your context file isn't getting loaded.

Comment: its working. had to add componantscan
@ComponentScan("com.inject.spring")

Comment: Then why the XML file.?